# Force and initial height of thrown object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

You stand at the earth's surface, and you throw a ball of mass *m1* into the air perpendicular to the surface. Let *g* at the surface be 9.81m/s^2.
You know two points (height:*h1*, *h2* and time:*t1*,*t2*) of the trajectory of the ball.
However the time(*t0*), height(*h0*) and force(*F*) at which the ball was thrown is unknown.
How do we find **an** initial height, time and force the object was thrown with?

We assume there are multiple solutions to this problem. (e.g.: throwing the ball at a lower height with more force compared throwing the ball at a higher point with less force.) Any of these solutions would be of interest to us.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we ignore air resistance, between $t_1$ and $t_2$ there are no forces acting on the ball besides gravity so with both the time and distance we can compute the velocity the ball would need to be traveling to be at both points. With $a=-9.81$, integrate twice to get the position function.
$$ x(t)= -9.81\frac{t^2}{2}+C_0t+C_1.$$
Plug in the two conditions that you have. Because the equation of motion is a second order differential equation, two conditions are enough to specify the constants.
$$ x(0)=1.652024= C_1$$
$$ x(.075)=1.785268 = -.05518125+.075C_1 \Rightarrow C_1=24.539$$
The equation assumes that no other forces except gravity are present and that the ball doesn't travel far enough that $g$ changes.

This equation of motion will be valid for any time after you stop acting on the ball with a throwing force. So for any $t<t_1$ there will be a unique position at which the ball is at as long as $t$ is after it leaves your hand.

The force an object is thrown at is impossible to tell from the given information. Imagine two scenarios. First, you hit the ball with a bat. In this case the force acting on the ball is huge, but it happens over a short duration. The ball quickly accelerates until it leaves the bat at a speed $V_0$. Now imagine instead putting the ball in a giant sling shot. The force of the slingshot bands is much less than the baseball bat, but this force is applied over a much longer time interval. When the ball leaves the slingshot, imagine it also is traveling at $V_0$ at that instant.

In these two situations the ball is moving with the same speed under gravity and it's motion after $t_0$ will look exactly the same. You can't tell what the forces on the object were as it was being thrown with only data from later in flight. The velocity at $t_0$ is the most you can deduce.